# $\sup\{\lambda_d(A): A \subseteq \mathbb R^d \text{ at most countable}\}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How can I calculate $\sup\{\lambda_d(A): A \subseteq \mathbb R^d \text{ at most countable}\}$

I know since $A$ is countable, I can write $A$ as a union of its elements.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Since $A$ is countable, I can write $A$ as a union of its elements.

Comment: Write it in the body , not in comment .

Comment: What does $\lambda_d(A)$ represent? From your tags (but nowhere else), I can think of what it might mean, but since the question is trivial for what I'm thinking of, I'm not very confident that what I'm thinking it means is what you intend it to mean.

Comment: Countable sets are always null, no? So the supremum is zero